# Reach content of variable in another method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to reach the content of `matchData` from a Vue method. I'm able to `console.log(this.matchData)`, but not able to get its content.

When I `console.log(this.matchData[0].matchScores[0])` under method `readMatchPlayerScoreIds()` I get:

> vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'matchScores' of undefined"

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      matchData: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    readMatches() {
      db.collection("matches")
        .get()
        .then((queryMatchSnapshot) => {
          queryMatchSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            this.matchData = [];
            this.matchData.push({
              awayscore: doc.data().awayscore,
              homeScore: doc.data().homeScore, 
              matchScores: doc.data().matchscores,
            })
          });
          console.log(this.matchData[0].matchScores[0])
        });
      },

      readMatchPlayerScoreIds() {
          console.log(this.matchData[0].matchScores[0])
      }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.readMatches();
    this.readMatchPlayerScoreIds();
  },
};
```

Comment: Where/how are you calling both methods?

Comment: Hi @Daniel_Knights, thanks for your replay. I`ve updated the post.

Comment: You are calling `readMatchPlayerScoreIds` before the matchData is loaded. I suppose the db call is async, isn't it? A quick fix would be to do call `readMatchPlayerScoreIds` inside the `then` block after the data has been set.

Comment: You are right, this worked. Thank you - you saved my day! As you write, this is async db. I might need to edit the topic of the post here. How do you suggest I Go ahead and store data from readMatches() and then "push" it to readMatchPlayerScoreIds()?

Comment: @ChristofferEndresen use promises.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are fetching data from the db **asynchronously**, the data will be empty until the db call was completed. You should read the data after the Promise has been resolved. (reformulating my comment as answer).

One way to do it, could be to return the Promise from `readMatches`:

```
    export default {
  data() {
    return {
      matchData: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    readMatches() {
      return db.collection("matches")
        .get()
        .then((queryMatchSnapshot) => {
          queryMatchSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            // this.matchData = []; // <= why would you reset it in each loop?
            this.matchData.push({
              awayscore: doc.data().awayscore,
              homeScore: doc.data().homeScore, 
              matchScores: doc.data().matchscores,
            })
          });
          console.log(this.matchData[0].matchScores[0])
        });
      },

      readMatchPlayerScoreIds() {
          console.log(this.matchData[0].matchScores[0])
      }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.readMatches()
        .then(() => this.readMatchPlayerScoreIds());
  },
};
```

But it depends on what you want do to in `readMatchPlayerScoreIds` method body.

Also, be aware not to reset `matchData` in the `forEach` loop.

Comment: @ChristofferEndresen feel free to accept the answer if it helped :)